# SublimeText linting Python3 with pyflakes in virtualenv

Tags: python, sublimetext3, virtualenv, sublimelinter, pyflakes

When I open my Python files in Sublime and delete simple things like : at the end of `def myFunction():`, then I expect the linter to add a red circle in the gutter. But I see nothing in the gutter.

I notice at the bottom of the Sublime window it says "pyflakes(erred)"

---

**Installing the dependencies**

```
# Sublime v 3.1.1
# Sublime package install SublimeLinter
# Sublime package install SublimeLinter-pyflakes

pip3 install pyflakes
which pyflakes
# /Users/macbook/Desktop/my_virtual_env/bin/pyflakes
```

Trying to tell my linter the path to use in **"MyProj.sublime-project"** settings

```
{
    "folders":[
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "SublimeLinter.linters.pyflakes.python": "/Users/macbook/Desktop/my_virtual_env/bin/python3"
}
```

---

**UPDATE: Sublime console output** upon loading views.py

```
SublimeLinter: #10 linter.py:907: 'pyflakes' is linting 'views.py'
SublimeLinter: #10 python_linter.py:42: pyflakes: wanted python is 'None'
SublimeLinter: #10 python_linter.py:93: pyflakes: trying to use globally installed pyflakes
SublimeLinter: #10 python_linter.py:101: WARNING: cannot locate 'pyflakes'. Fill in the 'python' or 'executable' setting.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49099993/7976758

Comment: @phd both of those are already installed

Answer (score 0):

These settings go under the key `settings`. E.g.

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
    ],

    "settings": {
        "SublimeLinter.linters.pyflakes.python": "..."
    }
}
```